# Problems removing case sensitivity while searching strings

Tags: string, python-2.7

I'm learning python using open courseware from MIT and one of the problem sets is to learn how to use classes to search RSS feeds for subjects of interest. I am not sure why I am getting the error displayed below. I am trying to convert both the search word string and the string from the news story object to all lowercase before trying to find the word - that way there if the search word is 'soft', then the trigger should fire on a string such as 'Koalas are soft and cuddly' and also 'Soft sandpaper is not effective'.

```
import string

class NewsStory(object):
    #news story is defined by 5 strings: guid, title, subject, summary, and link
    def __init__(self, guid, title, subject, summary, link):
        self.guid = guid
        self.title = title
        self.subject = subject
        self.summary = summary
        self.link = link
    def get_guid(self):
        return self.guid
    def get_title(self):
        return self.title
    def get_subject(self):
        return self.subject
    def get_summary(self):
        return self.summary
    def get_link(self):
        return self.link

class Trigger(object):
    #abstract class
    def evaluate(self, story):
        """
        Returns True if an alert should be generated
        for the given news item, or False otherwise.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError

# Whole Word Triggers
# Problems 2-5

# TODO: WordTrigger
class WordTrigger(Trigger):
    def __init__(self, word):
        #make search word all lowercase to remove case sensitivity
        self.word = string.lower(word)

    def is_word_in(self, text):
        #make text string from news story all lowercase to remove case sensitivity
        self.text = string.lower(text)
        #use the find method of the string class
        #it returns the lowest index where substring s is found in string; returns -1 if substring not found
        return string.find(self.text, self.word) > -1

# TODO: TitleTrigger, this subclass of WordTrigger will trigger on search term that is found in the title string of the news story object
class TitleTrigger(WordTrigger):
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = string.lower(word)

    def evaluate(self, story):
        #story is an instance of the NewsStory class
        title = story.get_title
        return super(TitleTrigger, self).is_word_in(title)

#make news story object
news1 = NewsStory('1234','it is raining dogs and cats','animals falling from sky','3 dogs and 2 cats fell from sky','www.cat.com')
#make TitleTrigger object
testTrig = TitleTrigger('cats')
testTrig.evaluate(news1)
```

The error that I am scratching my head over is displayed below:

```
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/David/Documents/Python2_7/Unit 2/postonline.py", line 61, in <module>
    testTrig.evaluate(news1)
  File "C:/Users/David/Documents/Python2_7/Unit 2/postonline.py", line 55, in evaluate
    return super(TitleTrigger, self).is_word_in(title)
  File "C:/Users/David/Documents/Python2_7/Unit 2/postonline.py", line 42, in is_word_in
    self.text = string.lower(text)
  File "C:\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\string.py", line 228, in lower
    return s.lower()
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `super` ?

Comment: You put `title = story.get_title`. That means you're assigning `title` the method `story.get_title`. You probably mean `story.get_title()`, which is the result of calling that method. You need the parentheses.

Comment: @khelwood I thought that using super was how you have to access a method in the superclass from the subclass, but I might be wrong about that.

Comment: You can call a method defined in a superclass just using `self.method_name()` as long as you haven't overridden it.

Comment: Also you don't need to use the `string` module at all. The `str` type has methods like [`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) and [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)

Comment: @khelwood I saw your comment on forgetting the () after story.get_title ! That was it!!! I can't believe that I was scratching my head over such a small oversight!!! I made the change and it works! I also will make the other changes such as not using string.x and not using super to streamline things